# Как отобразить кнопку, когда хоть один из элементов активен, и скрыть ее, когда ни один элемент не выбран

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть на странице двадцать элементов (кнопок в одном дизайне). Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на любой из элементов появлялся объект (еще одна кнопка, но в другом стиле). Но когда ни один элемент не будет активный, нужно чтобы объект исчезал. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать это действие. Долго думал, но не нашел решения. Вот HTML-код для удобства:

```
<ul class="genre-list">
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Comedy</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Criminal</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Detective</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Thriller</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Romance</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">War</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Historical</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Supernatural</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Drama</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Western</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Adventure</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Political</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Sci-Fi</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Musical</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Fantasy</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Biography</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Horror</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Action</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Disaster</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Sports</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>

            <button class="submit-btn" id="submitBtn">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </button>
```

CSS-код:

```
.genre-list {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
padding-top: 120px;
}

.genre-item {
margin: 60px 70px;
transition: all 0.8s;
}

.genre-item-btn {
width: 120px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 23px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #202020;
border: none;
outline: none;
border-radius: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
cursor: pointer;
user-select: none;
transition: all 0.4s;
}

.genre-item-btn.active {
outline: 5px solid #ff8a00;
}

.submit-btn {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 75%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
width: 147px;
height: 52px;
background: #fff;
border: 3px solid #21ebff;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #21ebff 0%, #21ebff 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff     
100%);
background-size: 200% 100%;
background-position: 100% 0;
transition: background-position 0.5s;
}

.submit-btn:hover {
background-position:0 0;
}

.arrow {
display: inline-flex;
position: relative;
width: 0;
height: 20px;
cursor: pointer;

margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
display: inline-flex;
position: absolute;
content: '';
}

.arrow:before {
top: 8px;
right: -50px;
width: 40px;
height: 3px;
background-color: #21ebff; 
transition: all 0.6s;
}

.arrow:after {
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
top: 2px;
right: -51px;
border-top: 3px solid #21ebff;
border-right: 3px solid #21ebff;
transform: rotate(45deg);
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.submit-btn:hover .arrow:before{
background-color: #fff;
}

.submit-btn:hover .arrow:after{
border-top: 3px solid #fff;
border-right: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

JS-код:

```
document.querySelector('.genre-list').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
event.target.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю правильно ли я вас понял, но надеюсь помог вам ^-^

```js
const genreItem = document.querySelectorAll('.genre-item');
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submitBtn');
for (let i = 0; i < genreItem.length; i++) {
  genreItem[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  for (let i = 0; i < genreItem.length; i++) {
    if (genreItem[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      submitBtn.classList.add('active');
      return;
    } else submitBtn.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.genre-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.genre-item {
  margin: 60px 70px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.genre-item-btn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202020;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.genre-item-btn.active {
  outline: 5px solid #ff8a00;
}

.submit-btn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 147px;
  height: 52px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #21ebff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #21ebff 0%, #21ebff 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}

.submit-btn:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.arrow:before {
  top: 8px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #21ebff;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}

.arrow:after {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 2px;
  right: -51px;
  border-top: 3px solid #21ebff;
  border-right: 3px solid #21ebff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.submit-btn:hover .arrow:before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.submit-btn:hover .arrow:after {
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="genre-list">
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Comedy</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Criminal</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Detective</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Thriller</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Romance</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">War</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Historical</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Supernatural</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Drama</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Western</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Adventure</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Political</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Sci-Fi</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Musical</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Fantasy</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Biography</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Horror</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Action</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Disaster</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="btn">Sports</button>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>

<button class="submit-btn" id="submitBtn">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы очень мне помогли. Это то, что нужно было)

Comment: Извини, но если это правильный ответ, можно поставить галочку? ^-^ Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Конечно, полностью заслужено. Я просто пока что новый пользователь, еще не со всем разобрался. Галочку поставил)